# Invalid column name / Ambiguous column name Error

Tags: mysql

```
select sno,id,name,city,country ,sales,profit from emp
inner join student
on id=student_id
```

> error:-Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'sno'.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Ambiguous column name 'sales'.

Comment: Check your table structure first if you have sno field

Comment: also you have sales field both in emp and student tables. In your select you should explicit specify which field you want

Comment: i have 2 tables and i want to combine them....

Comment: 101 RAVI HYDERABAD 102 4000
101 raj jail 100 2000
2 venky india 2334 22222

Comment: how to combine this 2 tables....query??????

Comment: Please mention what do you mean by combine them, what these values are and what you have tried for this so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited the topic to something sensible.  I have also marked up your sql (with4 leading spaces) and errors with >.

Comment: Use table alias letters to distinguish the two tables. Then use this alias letter and dot then your colum name

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of the comments are saying, you need to alias the tables you're joining so it makes sense to mysql. Since I don't have the full column names from each table I can only make an assumption on the correct alias's

```
select 
s.sno,
e.id,
s.name,
s.city,
s.country ,
s.sales,
s.profit 
from emp e 
inner join student s
on e.id = s.student_id
```

You're obviously going to have to change the column alias's so they conform to the correct table alias.

Basically the error is saying, "Hey.. you have the column "sales" in both the "student" and "emp" table, please tell me a little bit better (via way of an alias) which one I should use.